# Storing app / site settings within mongodb using mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I have been developing a node.js based site which is already running successfully live and it uses mongodb as the backend storage using the mongoose.

The thing is that, I want to implement some configurable settings for site (which should be able to configured using the /backend/ page).

So I've to find out a way to store all those settings using the mongoose but I couldn't came with a schema that can fit the thing.

```
var mongoose        = require('mongoose');

var SettingsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
});

mongoose.model('Settimgs', SettingsSchema);
```

Is there anyway that I can force a schema to have only a single document? So I can use the above schema with only one document and put all my required settings there.

Other than I've came with another idea where settings-schema collection will host multiple documents each with their unique section name as the following, but then the contents of the schema for each section should be different. One idea I came with is just storing section specific json as an object data without giving the model details;

```
var mongoose        = require('mongoose');

var SettingsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, lowercase: true, trim: true, unique: true, required: true },  // the settings section name
    ...
    JSON-Object or JSON-string here?
    Is {data: Object} a possible usage?
});

mongoose.model('Settimgs', SettingsSchema);
```

But if I can find a way to define models for sections, it'll be lot better & testable -- like a model for backend-settings and another for front-end settings which should be all stored in Settings collection somehow.

So what I'd like to have is;

```
var BackendSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
.. backend related settings here..
});

var FrontendSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
.. frontend related settings here..
});
```

and finally have a master settings-schema to cover these together and save all those documents to a single collection.

I've searched for a while to see if any interesting reads are available on the topic but had no luck -- will be nice if you can post in case that you are aware of one.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about Mongoose Discriminators [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html)

According to the documentation

> Discriminators are a schema inheritance mechanism. They enable you to have multiple models with overlapping schemas on top of the same underlying MongoDB collection.

I wish this help you